# interpreting $(1-t)f(a)+tf(b)$ from $f((1-t)a+tb)\leq (1-t)f(a)+tf(b)$

Tags: calculus

For a convex function

$f((1-t)a+tb)\leq (1-t)f(a)+tf(b)$

holds. I understand how the graph looks like

but why is the equation of the secant line

$(1-t)f(a)+tf(b)$?

Can anyone pleasae give me a good proof?

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$

Comment: @nbubis will have to learn latex as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a single line that passes between any two points.

Since the function $g(x)=(1-t)f(a)+tf(b)$ is a line, and $g(0)=f(a), g(1) = f(b)$, it follows that $g(x)$ is the only line passing between those points.

Answer (score 1):

By point-slope form of the secant line, we have $$y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$$ for any given point $(x_0,y_0)$ on the line and any $(x,y)$ on the line distinct from the given point. Well, *one* point on the secant line is $(a,f(a)),$ so $$y-f(a)=m(x-a)$$ is an equation for the line. To calculate the slope, we need *two* points (which, fortunately, we have), giving us $$m=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a},$$ and so $$y-f(a)=\frac{\bigl(f(b)-f(a)\bigr)(x-a)}{b-a}=\frac{x-a}{b-a}\bigl(f(b)-f(a)\bigr)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}f(b)-\frac{x-a}{b-a}f(a),$$ whence $$y=\left(1-\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)f(a)+\frac{x-a}{b-a}f(b).$$ The idea, then, is to make the substitution $$x=(1-t)a+tb,$$ which is equivalent to $t=\frac{x-a}{b-a},$ and we're done.